# Which movies have the most realistic artificial intelligence?

Tags: applications, social, academia

I want to give some examples of AI via movies to my students. There are [many movies that include AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_intelligence_films), whether being the main character or extras.

Which movies have the most realistic (the most possible or at least close to being made in this era) artificial intelligence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Just A Rather Very Intelligent System (J.A.R.V.I.S.)](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/J.A.R.V.I.S.) in [Iron Man](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_(film)) (and related films, such as The Avengers) is something (a personal assistant) that people are already trying to develop, so JARVIS is a quite realistic artificial intelligence. Examples of existing [personal assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_assistant) are [Google Assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Assistant) (integrated into [Google Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Home) devices), [Cortana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortana), [Siri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri) and [Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa). There are [other virtual assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_assistant#Comparison_of_notable_assistants), but, unfortunately, there aren't many reliable open-source ones. Note that JARVIS is way more intelligent and capable than the other mentioned personal assistants.

Similarly, [HAL 9000](https://2001.fandom.com/wiki/HAL_9000), in [2001: A Space Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)), is a sentient artificial intelligence which can be considered a personal assistant.

Comment: but I think there is a large gap between JARVIS and Siri :/ I'm not a Siri's user, but is it able to process such a natural dialogue and do such an action? are we close enough in that technology?

Comment: @QLAN As I say in this answer, JARVIS is way more capable than existing PAs, but I think it is the most realistic AI portrayed in movies (that I can think of now). I don't exactly know when real PAs will be as capable as JARVIS or HAL, but I expect at least 1-2 decades, but maybe a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention WOPR from [War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames), maybe is an old movie for your students, but it is a more realistic IA centered around the problem of playing board games (if you exclude the part about deciding that a game is not worth the time).

Also I remember an artificial assistant in ["The Time machine"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268695/) that was more convincing than J.A.R.V.I.S because it is not so intelligent, I remember it more like an agent that can find and read you wikipedia articles, but without reasoning about them a lot, but I could be wrong.

The robot companion in [Moon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/) is also interesting and comical as it is like a small child that has been told to cheat but can't disobey direct orders.

Other films go around the dilema of creating AGI, like, "Blade runner", "The bicentenary Man", Spilbergs' "I.A.", "Her", or "Ex Machina", they are more interesting from a philosofical point of view (they are all very similar to Mary Shelley's Frankenstein) because the actual implementation is unconceivable right now.